# Fonts size is changing when scrolling in gridview

Tags: ios, gridview

I have a gridview with images. Scrolling is some laggy, and when I scroll, labels' font sizes in the grids are changing.

Is it because of memory?

Comment: Could you please post your code in datasource protocol methods?

Answer (score 1):

The font size changing is most likely not a memory issue.

Look for code that is modifying the font size in your `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` (assuming your gridView is a collection view). This method will be called every time you are scrolling and is probably the reason why the font sizes are changing.

```
CGFloat fontSize;
UIFont *font = [UIFont systemFontOfSize:fontSize++];
```

If you are having memory issues, make sure you are using 
`dequeueReusableCellWithReuseIdentifier:forIndexPath:` in `collectionView:cellForItemAtIndexPath:` so that you are not re-creating the cells every time.

Also, reuse the imageView by changing the image rather than creating a new imageView every time.

```
UIImage *image;
[imageView setImage:image];
```

Apart from the suggestions I've listed above, I'd need to see the rest of your code to advise further.